# Syntax highlighting does not work in this post

Tags: bug

[How to dynamically fill the structure which is a pointer to pointer of arrays in C++ implementing xfs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30184208/140367)

I think the words `typedef` and `struct` should be highlighted but aren't.

[image: screenshot]

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36

I tried editing and reindenting the code blocks, but it seems they were already indented correctly. Am I looking something over?

Comment: It doesn't have a language tag on the question - how does it know what highlighter to use?

Comment: @Joe I was under the impression that SO uses a generic highlighter, is that no longer the case? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/132066 The question even has a language hint comment in it.

Comment: Google Prettify uses a generic highlighter by default, but I don't think I've ever seen that on any SE site.

Comment: "**If** there's more than one tag that has syntax highlighting, it uses a default " - from the page you link to @Tamás. Pick a language tag or force the highlighting.

Comment: It's always been the case that you need to tag the question with the appropriate language tag in order to get the correct syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hint for c++ is not:

```
<!-- language: c++ -->
```

but

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->
```

and must appear **immediately** before each code block. Or add one `language-all` comment to have it applied to all code blocks in your post:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-cpp -->
```

I have edited the question.

Comment: Shouldn't the first one also work? It should take the default highlighting of the [tag:c++] tag IIRC.

Comment: It's not my question, but thanks.

Comment: @TamásSzelei - sorry, I shouldn't have made that assumption.

Comment: @Stijn - what do you mean? The question doesn't have the [tag:c++] tag.

Comment: That's alright, I only pointed that out because the question is not of great quality.

Comment: @ChrisF I mean when you use `<!-- language: c++ -->`, it will use the default highlighting associated with the [tag:c++] tag, so it's equivalent to `<!-- language: lang-cpp -->`

Comment: @Stijn - it doesn't though (or at least didn't appear to when I tried that). The key bit is that the hint must appear immediately before the code block and it doesn't carry on to subsequent blocks.